# Request to a firestore db with a reference type field not working

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, postman

I have the following code for a get request:

```
app.get('/getPetByOwner', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { ownerId } = req.query;

    if (!ownerId) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'OwnerId is required in the query parameters.' });
    }
    const mascotasCollection = await admin.firestore().collection('pets').where('owner', '==', ownerId).get();
    
    if(mascotasCollection.empty) return res.status(404).json({error:"pets not found for the provided user"});
    
    const mascotasData = [];

    mascotasCollection.forEach((doc) => {
      mascotasData.push({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      });
    });

    res.status(200).json(mascotasData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in getMascotasByOwner:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error.' });
  }
});
```

But it always return a 404, even when providing an existing user id with pets.
The structure of the db is something like this:

[image]

I tried with different users but none of them work. The postman request is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to convert the `ownerId` numeric value of `1` to a string? Firestore Doc IDs are of String type. Or try with the Doc ID `S7MSM...`

Comment: Yeah, I tried with the other users but doesnt work.

Comment: Forget my above comment, it's a stupid mistake from my side, you are not querying by Doc ID.... New question: What is the type of the `owner` field?

Comment: It is a reference data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `owner` field is of [Firestore Data Type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) **Reference**, the value passed to the `where()` method needs to be define as a `DocumentReference`, as follows:

```
const { ownerId } = req.query;

// ...

const ownerIdDocRef = admin.firestore()
   .collection('users')
   .doc(ownerId);

const mascotasCollection = await admin.firestore().collection('pets').where('owner', '==', ownerIdDocRef).get();
```